# Securely passing Authentication token data from Laravel to javaScript for AJAX call

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, socket.io, laravel-5.4

I'm developing an application that relies in external datasource that will be called by AJAX and socketIo. To call this data, I need to send an Authentication code that will be unique for each user. (this key will be stored in local database).

My question is, how do I secure this code? I'm currently using 
https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer
to get the auth code into my js application, but it shows in the source code. Is there any best options?  Really appreciate any help.

Controller

```
JavaScript::put([
            'Variable' => $variables,
            'token' => $user->token,
   ]);
```

this is what I see when opening the source code:

```
<script>window.jsparse = window.jsparse || {};jsparse.Variable = ["5ba7757273efc33c92a58ebd"];jsparse.token = "BBKAUTHke123471-028395234";</script>
```

Comment: We need more information. Explain how you store the token inside the js app and how long your token is valid, for example.